# HashWithIndifferentAccess issue with a Ruby App

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have two apps that talk to the same database. One is a Ruby on Rails app and another is a console app written in Ruby.

In the Rails app, I save a bunch of settings which are saved to a column called "notification_settings".. I have the following in my model;

```
serialize :notification_settings, Hash
```

This causes the value in the column to be stored as such

```
--- !map:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess 
test: !map:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess 
  email: "1"
```

etc

When I do the same thing in my Ruby app, the hash is simply saved as a normal hash. Even if i do something like; (in my Ruby app model.rb)

```
  hash = HashWithIndifferentAccess.new(self.notification_settings)
    hash[:test][:email] = 0
    self.update_attribute(:notification_settings, hash)
```

How can I get the Ruby app to save the record the exact same way (HashWithIndifferentAccess) as my Rails app is saving the record?

Comment: are you using active_record in ruby app?

Comment: Sounds like this explains why: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8918434/unable-to-serialize-as-activesupporthashwithindifferentaccess-anymore

Comment: Yes, in my Ruby app I have require 'active_record' && require 'active_support'

Comment: Iltempo's answer did the trick. See

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8918434/unable-to-serialize-as-activesupporthashwithindifferentaccess-anymore