# Rails bad Hash serialization... sometimes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, serialization, hash, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I can't understand why sometimes the serialization produce this (I want):

```
--- !map:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess 
first_question: "Pas \xC3\xA9quilibr\xC3\xA9 -perte"
second_question: "Compte de r\xC3\xA9sultat"
```

And sometimes that (I don't want):

```
---
first_question: ! "1- Mettre en place le renvoi de son téléphone vers sa boite vocale\r\n2-
  Se mettre dans un bureau fermé pour travailler\r\n3- Savoir dire non"
second_question: ! "1- mes collègues\r\n2- le téléphone\r\n"
```

I recently did a fresh deploy and the data is now being stored without
the !map:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess part, which is
breaking my app!

Gemfile

```
ruby '1.9.2' # added this line 3 days ago...
gem 'rails', '3.1.10'
```

Course model

```
# encoding: utf-8
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  # [...]
  serialize :estart_scenario_data, Hash
  # [...]
  validate :validate_estart_scenario_data
  # [...]
  def add_data(prefix, params, is_done=true)
    self["#{prefix}_data"] = params
    self["#{prefix}_done_at"] = Time.now if is_done
  end
  # [...]
  private
    def validate_estart_scenario_data
      unless self.estart_scenario_data.blank?
        errors.add(:first_question, "Answer the first question") if self.estart_scenario_data[:first_question].blank?
        errors.add(:second_question, "Answer the second question") if self.estart_scenario_data[:second_question].blank?
      end
    end
end
```

I used to get values with this:

```
self.estart_scenario_data[:first_question]
```

And now it produce nothing. I have to change the line with:

```
self.estart_scenario_data["first_question"]
```

BUT, it produce an error "invalid byte sequence in UTF-8".

What happened?
Now I have 2 kinds of Hash in the DB !

How can I revert this?

Comment: Bad serialization with ruby 1.9.2p290, it seems there's a problem with psych here. I will try `YAML::ENGINE.yamler = 'syck'` in my application.rb...

Answer (score 0):

`psyck` and `ruby 1.9.2` are not playing well.
I had to upgrade to `ruby 1.9.3`.

Answer (score 0):

`--- !map:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess` means this is an instance of `ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess`, the second one means it's an instance of `Hash`.

You're probably storing `params` from you controller, which is an instance of `ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess`

Comment: Sure, I understand that. But I can't figure out why.. because I didn't change anything but the Gemfile.

Comment: Found this:Psych YAML-izes ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess as a standard hash is an oustanding issue on Psych's Github. Seems to be fixed in 1.9.3 though. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8918434/unable-to-serialize-as-activesupporthashwithindifferentaccess-anymore